# White / colorless regions in plots

Tags: plotting

I made the following contourplots, with Mathematica 12.2.0.0 however they show color-empty regions, which is apparently an error in the plotting or in the representation of the function. Does anyone know what these empty regions are?

I attach the  codes and images.

```
  u[r_, phi_] := 
  0.018778093057411193`*
    Sum[BesselJ[n, 1.5*r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}] + 
   Sum[(0.00042221117650360055`*BesselJ[n, 3*r] + 
       3.026131439416714`*^-10*BesselY[n, 3*r])*Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 
     5}] + Sum[
    5.062485836886407`*^-9*HankelH1[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}];

   u[x, y]:= TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
     u[r, phi], {r, phi} -> {x, y}]



ContourPlot[Re[u[x, y]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

[image: Plot]

If I change the name of the transformed field to

```
 v[x, y]:= TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
         u[r, phi], {r, phi} -> {x, y}]
```

It gives these plots:

[image: Plots]

However, if , still using v, I use a different plotting scheme as given:

```
  contourPotentialPlot1 = 
  ContourPlot[Re[v[x, y]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic, Contours -> 15, Axes -> True, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"];

potential1 = 
  Plot3D[Re[v[x, y]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], Blue}, {Opacity[.8], Orange}}, 
   Lighting -> "Neutral"];

level = -1.2 10^8; gr = 
 Graphics3D[{Texture[contourPotentialPlot1], EdgeForm[], 
   Polygon[{{-400, -300, level}, {400, -300, level}, {400, 300, 
      level}, {-400, 300, level}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"];

Show[potential1, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .6}, 
 FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}]
```

Then I get the same white region as above, using CLOUD:

[image: Cloud]

It does not give a proper field inside the "flower".

If I plot the Real part in 3D, I get the similar pattern, but at a different scale:

[image]

And if I combine the contour and the object in 3D I still get white regions in the contour, although they are clearly not white (as they grow in the z axis)

```
Show[
 potential1,
 DeleteCases[
  potential1 /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest___] :>
    GraphicsComplex[
     PadRight[pts[[All, ;; 2]], {Automatic, 3}, 
      Rescale[PlotRange[potential1][[3]], (* the whole Rescale[..] code can be replaced by any number/level *)
        {0, 1},
        {-0.05, 1}                        (* project 5% lower than original plot range - change as desired *)
        ][[1]]],
     rest],
  Verbatim[Rule][VertexNormals, _], Infinity],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 3D_contour]

and finally in the evaluated contourplots:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Re[v[x, y]]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Evaluated_contour]

Comment: This is because the values of the function are out of the default PlotRange. So, play with it. As the first attempt try the option `PlotRange->All` .

Comment: Doesn't make a diifference

Comment: Done 12.2.0. Can Complexcontourplot be an alternative? The function is rather messy in Cartesian system, I have no idea how to make that function compatible for Complexcontourplot.

Comment: @vqngs the code you've posted doesn't generate that flower shape for me and using `PlotRange->All` fixes the empty whitespace in the plot it _does_ generate. The issue is in your reusing the symbol `u` for a polar-coordinate transformed version of this. You'd be better off defining `v[x_, y_]: = TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian",  u[r, phi], {r, phi} -> {x, y}];` and using `v` in the plotting function. With that fix, `PlotRange->All` fixes everything except for what I'm assuming is a branch cut, but it also hides any structure because the excluded regions are much higher in value

Comment: @b3m2a1 This does not work, it only changes the color inside. Have a look at the extension on the question.

Answer (score 1):

A 3D plot may be instructive:

```
Plot3D[Re[u[x, y]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}]
```

[image]

The values of the function in the white region is much higher than in the displayed region.

With the option "PlotRange->All":

```
Plot3D[Re[u[x, y]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note the scale of the z-axis.

Comment: We have to visualize the absolute center, where those "flower like" patterns emerge

Comment: `Plot3D[Evaluate[Re[u[x, y]]], {x, -0.3, 0.3}, {y, -0.3, 0.3}]` will give a much different plot.

Comment: `ClippingStyle` should also be mentioned here (@vqngs).